# React Native iOS application id mismatch

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, apple-push-notifications

I am generating APNS certificates for my React Native project to uplaod them to firebase. I found a weird thing: appId prefix in XCode and AppStoreConnect are different? There's no such problem with bundleId. Is it ok and doest it influence on sending push notifications? Also, how can I solve this problem? Thanks!

[image]
[image]